# Laravel 4.2 - using ::firstOrCreate and determining what actually happened?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When using `Model::firstOrCreate` in Laravel 4.2, is there a way of knowing which happened,, first or create?

Let me explain,,, My understanding is that with ::firstOrCreate a record is created IF it doesn't exist OR values of records containing argument array data are returned.

So if I have something like this:

```
// Auth::user()->id; returns 7

$person = Persons::firstOrCreate(array(
    'approver' => 123,
    'receiver' => Auth::user()->id,
    'plan' => 'gold',
));
```

And I have these records

```
  approver | receiver  |  plan
____________________________________
    123    |     7     |  silver
____________________________________
    128    |     7     |  gold
____________________________________
    123    |     7     |  platinum
____________________________________
```

Then a new record will be created

```
  approver | receiver  |  plan
____________________________________
    123    |     7     |  silver
____________________________________
    128    |     7     |  gold
____________________________________
    123    |     7     |  platinum
____________________________________
    123    |     7     |  gold
____________________________________
```

And if I run the above code again then the new value will not be created and this record will be returned

```
  approver | receiver  |  plan
____________________________________

    123    |     7     |  gold
____________________________________
```

But if my code looks like this

```
$person = Persons::firstOrCreate(array(
    'approver' => 123,
    'receiver' => Auth::user()->id
));
```

These records will be returned

```
  approver | receiver  |  plan
____________________________________
    123    |     7     |  silver
____________________________________
    123    |     7     |  platinum
____________________________________
    123    |     7     |  gold
____________________________________
```

If my understanding of ::firstOrCreate is not correct please help me understand it better.

And as I mentioned,, I am interested to know if there is a way to determine if CREATE of new record happened or not?

Comment: "These records will be returned". No. The first of those records will be returned. Not a collection.

Comment: Oh ok. I see. After I wrote the question I thought of that but i wasn't sure. I guess that is what the first stands for :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The model has a `wasRecentlyCreated` property:

```php
$person = Persons::firstOrCreate([
    'approver' => 123,
    'receiver' => auth()->id(),
    'plan' => 'gold',
]);

if ($person->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    // $person was created
} else {
    // $person was fetched
}
```

For older versions of Laravel, you can achieve what you want with `firstOrNew`:

```php
$person = Persons::firstOrNew([
    'approver' => 123,
    'receiver' => Auth::user()->id,
    'plan' => 'gold',
]);

if (! $person->id) {
    $person->save();

    // $person was created...
} else {
    // $person was fetched...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will be helpful.